# Dynamic Collection View Item Size in Interface Builder Xcode 6

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

I am curious if it is possible to configure collection view items to have variable/dynamic sizes from right inside storyboard?

With the introduction of adaptive layouts and the storyboard preview mode, it seems counterintuitive to me that we should be restricted to hardcoding collection view item sizes.  It also makes it a little more challenging to use the preview mode to debug your constraints.

See the below screenshot for an example.  In the screenshot I have a collection view displayed on 3 different phone sizes.  In my case I want each collection view item to be the entire size of the screen.  I've set the collection view background to red and the background of the first cell to be blue (the second one has a white background).  My collection view has constraints that pin it to the borders of the screen and you can see that it scales properly.  However, my collection view items remain the size that they were hardcoded in storyboard (320 x 600).
[image: Storyboard Preview Mode]

I can manually increase the cell size to match iPhone 6's screen and you can see that my constraints within the collection view scale nicely but now the preview mode looks messed up for the 4in and 5.5in sizes:
[image: Storyboard Preview Mode with larger CV item size]

FYI I know how to adjust collection view item sizes programmatically using the `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` and I am also aware of the super awesome new `estimatedItemSize` property for adaptive layouts so if necessary I can do this in code.  The issue I am trying to solve is that you cannot simultaneously preview a collection view in storyboard for more than just one size.

In my dream world I could attach constraints to the size of a collection view item...can it become reality?

Comment: iOS8 introduced support for auto layout in table / collection view cells.  This is covered in WWDC 2014 §226: "What's new in Collection Views".  I don't have the minute mark in my notes, but it's at the start.